# how to override the redirect function of cancel button in Display form?

Tags: javascript, custom-list, redirect

I have a custom list and I am showing some items on the home page. When the user clicks on a link it is sent to the display page. But, when you are on the display page, the cancel button returns the user to the list itself. I would like to redirect user back to the home page.

I know for save button there is a function called `PreSaveAction()`, but is there one for cancel button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add Source Parameter in the query string.

For eg: If your link is:

```
http://servername/sites/sitename/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=25
```

Then with Source Parameter your link will be:

```
http://servername/sites/sitename/Lists/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=25&Source=/sites/sitename/pages/home.aspx
```

This will redirect to the home page.

For reference: [Passing a Source Parameter on the Query String with Multiple Other Parameters](http://sympmarc.com/2009/10/20/passing-a-source-parameter-on-the-query-string-with-multiple-other-parameters/)

Comment: i had forgotten that completely. Thanks. It helped.